# SCSS duplicates wile importing from angular1.5 components

Tags: angularjs, typescript, sass, duplicates

Say I have multiple components that require the same SCSS file. When I am using webpack ExtractTextPlugin plugin I get output file with multiple duplications of the contents of this file. Is there a way to prevent extracting files that were already extracted in the output file?   1

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need the [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/)

"The CommonsChunkPlugin is an opt-in feature that creates a separate file (known as a chunk), consisting of common modules shared between multiple entry points. By separating common modules from bundles, the resulting chunked file can be loaded once initially, and stored in cache for later use. This results in pagespeed optimizations as the browser can quickly serve the shared code from cache, rather than being forced to load a larger bundle whenever a new page is visited."

```
...
    plugins: [
       new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "commons",
        filename: "commons.min.js",
        minChunks: 2
       })
    ]
...
```